# Datepicker on button after click

Tags: android, datepicker, android-databinding

I am looking for a solution to my problem. I want to make button in activity and after click I want to display date picker. How to do it in databindind? Any bind adapter?

Comment: share your databinding code.

Comment: I don't have any code, I just preparing to new project and this is my main problem.
I looked the answer two days and nothing, but I want to do it properly with data binding, that I just started learning. If you want I can paste my old code to show what I mean, but without data binding.

Comment: @user9897182 check my Answer below. just call that method in onClick of your button

Answer (score 1):

```
private void openDatePicker() {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    cal.set(year, month, day);
    final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getApplicationContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar choosen = Calendar.getInstance();
            choosen.set(view.getYear(), view.getMonth(), view.getDayOfMonth());
            Date date = choosen.getTime();
            // Do whatever you want
        }
    }, year, month, day);
    datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
    datePickerDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", datePickerDialog);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Data binding:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  void onClick(View view){
    openDatePicker();
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean and I want this implement in databinding version.

Comment: check now @user9897182

Answer (score 1):

Initialize DatePickerDialog

```
 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date;

date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
               /////// Here You will get Selected Date from Calendar ///////
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");
button.setText(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
            }

        };
```

Write this code on Button Click

```
new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialogTheme, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

Comment: Thanks! Works pretty well, but what if I want display chosen date in button?

Comment: Thanks! It's Working for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me and i'm using this in my code. I'm creating this class inside my activity itself.

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{
    private Calendar calendar;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        if (getActivity() != null)
        {
            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);

        // You may use different date format according to your use..
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.getDefault());

        String selectedDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime()); // this is the date which the user will select
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
```